# Apply NLTK Rake to each row in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I'd like to apply the Rake function (https://pypi.org/project/rake-nltk/) to each row in my dataframe.

I can apply the function individually to a specific row, but not append it to the dataframe.

This is what I have so far:

```
r = Rake(ranking_metric= Metric.DEGREE_TO_FREQUENCY_RATIO, language= 'english', min_length=1, max_length=4)
r.extract_keywords_from_text(test.document[177])
r.get_ranked_phrases() #prints a list of keywords
test['keywords'] = test.applymap(lambda x: r.extract_keywords_from_text(x)) #trying to apply it to each row.
```

It just runs indefinitely. I just want to append a new column to my dataframe 'test' called "keywords" that has the list of keywords from r.get_ranked_phrases().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

r.extract_keywords_from_text(x) will return you None

```
import pandas as pd
from  rake_nltk import Rake  

r = Rake()    

df=pd.DataFrame(data = ['machine learning and fraud detection are a must learn',
                  'monte carlo method is great and so is hmm,pca, svm and neural net',
                  'clustering and cloud',
                  'logistical regression and data management and fraud detection'] ,columns = ['Comments'])


 def rake_implement(x,r):
     r.extract_keywords_from_text(x)
     return r.get_ranked_phrases()

df['new_col'] =df['Comments'].apply(lambda x: rake_implement(x,r))
print(df['new_col'])
#o/p
0      [must learn, machine learning, fraud detection]
1    [monte carlo method, neural net, svm, pca, hmm...
2                                  [clustering, cloud]
3    [logistical regression, fraud detection, data ...
Name: new_col, dtype: object
```