# python Pandas |How to assign keywords extracted using rake function into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, cosine-similarity, countvectorizer

Im learning to make a content based book recommending system (reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-from-scratch-a-content-based-movie-recommender-with-natural-language-processing-25ad400eb243). I used rake function to extract keywords from 'Plot' column. How do I assign these keywords to a new column?

Im working with pandas, numpy, CountVectorizer, rake_nltk. I tried the following code:  `row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys())` but the column is still empty.

```py
import pandas as pd
from rake_nltk import Rake
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.read_csv('cleaned DATA set.csv')
df = df[['Book_ID','Title','Author','Genre1','Genre2','Plot']]


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plot = row['Plot']

    # instantiating Rake, by default it uses english stopwords from NLTK
    # and discards all puntuation characters as well
    r = Rake()

    # extracting the words by passing the text
    r.extract_keywords_from_text(plot)

    # getting the dictionary whith key words as keys and their scores as values
    key_words_dict_scores = r.get_word_degrees()

    # assigning the key words to the new column for the corresponding movie
    row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys())
```

I expect to see a new column named `'Key_words'` added that contains all keywords for corresponding book title.

Actual output showed that `'key_words'` column is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply NLTK Rake to each row in Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836477/apply-nltk-rake-to-each-row-in-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You missed this step of initializing a new column before for loop.

```
df['Key_words'] = ""
```

Comment: Oh im so sorry. i did do this step but i forgot to add it in this post. even with initializing new column it doesn't yield the result i need.

Comment: could you tell me what else im missing? im very new to python and NLP